# Date Picker noob

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker

I don't know where to ask for help. Well, let me be straight. Next week I am going to present my project in front of my panels which that means a lot to me. My system not finish 100%, and I am stuck at date picker stuff. I did spent like a whole day, download jquery (which I thought it will work) but still I cant. This is the silliest thing I ever do. Posting more than 1 same question, and I really need help. Seriously. I need to do date picker which enable user to select date and it will be store in db. Please. You may down voting me for doing this but I am down on my knee, seeking for help. A guide, steps or any tutorial on doing that as I am not an expert in asp.net,coding stuff. Please.

Comment: What *database* product with you?

Comment: Begging on your knees isn't going to get you help. Showing that you've made a reasonable effort to solve the problem yourself will. Show what you've tried. Post code. Show what doesn't work. Post the error.

Comment: Okay. Take few minutes, show what you have tried. All you need is just a date picker control?

Comment: Just a tip, it's all about understanding not copy pasting.

Comment: This may help you further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729311/asp-net-date-and-time-picker

Comment: Spent whole day and haven't tried to search?!

Comment: This is your third question in a row about a `DateTime` picker here on SO. Check the other answers people gave you before asking someone to give you "teh codez".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: include JQuery and JQuery UI libs in your page's header (between the HEAD and /HEAD tags):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

1. Add this code to your page after the BODY tag (copied from JQuery's website):

   ```
   <script>
     $(function() {
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
   </script>

   <div class="demo"><p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p></div>
   ```

Now when you click the input field, a datepicker should appear.

Answer (score 1):

Demo is here [JQueryUI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker)
Just import jquery first and next the jqueryUI library.

```
<SCRIPT>
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</SCRIPT>

<DIV class=demo>
    <P>Date: <INPUT id=datepicker type=text></P>
</DIV>
```